# SQL - GROUP BY and ORDER BY MIN

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have table with players results:

```
id | id_user | timems | status | cancel
```

Players choose between two status: 1 or 2 when they start play. Im make ranking of best times:

```
SELECT *, MIN(timems) AS besttime 
FROM `wyniki` 
WHERE NOT cancel=1 
GROUP BY id_user 
ORDER BY MIN(timems) ASC
```

And this is woking good but i dont know what 'besttime' is for what 'status'.

Comment: That `group by` usage is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is error prone

You can do this

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT id_user, status , MIN(timems) AS besttime FROM `wyniki` 
WHERE NOT cancel=1 GROUP BY id_user, status ORDER BY MIN(timems) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_user, 
       MIN(case when status = 1 then timems else null end) AS best_time_1,
       MIN(case when status = 2 then timems else null end) AS best_time_2
FROM wyniki 
WHERE cancel <> 1 
GROUP BY id_user 
ORDER BY MIN(timems) ASC
```